# Desenhar uma imagem pixel a pixel

Tags: java, swing, thread, multithreading

Estou tentando fazer um programinha besta mas não estou conseguindo.

Quero redesenhar uma imagem pixel a pixel aleatoriamente, fazendo isto com várias threads.

Não manjo muito de Java Swing, então estou me batendo bastante.

Fiz algumas pesquisas antes de postar, ao que entendi devo usar o `BufferedImage` para isto.

Encontrei um exemplo de multi-processamento que se aproxima do que eu gostaria de fazer.
A diferença é que ele realmente desenha uma imagem e faz isso linha a linha, eu gostaria de carregá-la, mas não consegui adaptar isto a minha necessidade.

Aqui está o fonte completo: [MultiProcessamento - Imagem](https://github.com/fernandoadam/JAVA_IMAGEM/blob/master/Multiprocessing.java).

E aqui onde ele desenha a imagem:

```
private class Runner extends Thread {
    double xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax;
    int maxIterations;
    int[] rgb;
    int[] palette;
    int width, height;
    int startRow, endRow;

    Runner(int startRow, int endRow) {
        this.startRow = startRow;
        this.endRow = endRow;
        width = image.getWidth();
        height = image.getHeight();
        rgb = new int[width];
        palette = new int[256];
        for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
            palette[i] = Color.getHSBColor(i / 255F, 1, 1).getRGB();
        xmin = -1.6744096740931858;
        xmax = -1.674409674093473;
        ymin = 4.716540768697223E-5;
        ymax = 4.716540790246652E-5;
        maxIterations = 10000;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            double x, y;
            double dx, dy;
            dx = (xmax - xmin) / (width - 1);
            dy = (ymax - ymin) / (height - 1);

            for (int row = startRow; row <= endRow; row++) { 
                y = ymax - dy * row;
                for (int col = 0; col < width; col++) {
                    x = xmin + dx * col;
                    int count = 0;
                    double xx = x;
                    double yy = y;
                    while (count < maxIterations && (xx * xx + yy * yy) < 4) {
                        count++;
                        double newxx = xx * xx - yy * yy + x;
                        yy = 2 * xx * yy + y;
                        xx = newxx;
                    }
                    if (count == maxIterations)
                        rgb[col] = 0;
                    else
                        rgb[col] = palette[count % palette.length];
                }
                if (!running) { 
                    return;
                }
                synchronized (image) {
                    image.setRGB(0, row, width, 1, rgb, 0, width);
                }
                display.repaint(0, row, width, 1); 
            }
        } finally {
            threadFinished();
        }
    }
}
```

Como posso fazer para carregar minha própria imagem e redesenhar os pixels?

---

## EDITADO:

Testei conforme o exemplo abaixo, mas ele não desenha pixel a pixel conforme o exemplo, parece que é desenhado em retângulos.

Segue a maneira que fiz. O que pode estar errado?? Estou usando JPanel e não Canvas.

```
private class Runner extends Thread {
    int width, height;
    Random randomi = new Random();
    Random randomj = new Random();
    Graphics g = image.getGraphics();

    Runner(int startRow, int endRow) {
        width = image.getWidth();
        height = image.getHeight();
    }

    public void run() {
        try {

            for (int xx = 0; xx < (width + height); xx++) {

                int i = randomi.nextInt(width);
                int j = randomj.nextInt(height);
                
                //System.out.println("i = " + i + "  j = " + j);
                //g.setColor(getColor(i, j));
                //g.drawLine(i, j, i, j);

                image.setRGB(i, j, getColor(i, j).getRGB());
                display.repaint(i, j, i, j);

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(5);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }    
            }    
        } finally {
            threadFinished();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Está longe de ser um bom código, mas dá para teres uma ideia de como funciona mais ao menos.

Este código faz

- pega na imagem
- depois desenha a imagem pixel por pixel aleatoriamente

No meu teste a imagem era de 60 por 60, como é aleatorio existe sempre pontos que a função não foi buscar, logo não pintou no ecrã a imagem completa...

Testa tu e vê se dá para tirares ideias para o que queres fazer.

**Codigo:**

```
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import org.openide.util.Exceptions;

public class PixelCanvas extends Canvas {

    private static final int WIDTH = 100;
    private static final int HEIGHT = 100;
    private static final Random random = new Random();
    private static final Random randomi = new Random();
    private static final Random randomj = new Random();
    private static BufferedImage image = null;

    public PixelCanvas() {
        getImg();
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
        for (int xx = 0; xx < 10000; xx++) {

            int i = randomi.nextInt(image.getWidth());
            int j = randomj.nextInt(image.getHeight());
            g.setColor(getColor(i, j));
            g.drawLine(i, j, i, j);


            try {
                Thread.sleep(1);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Exceptions.printStackTrace(ex);
            }

        }



    }

    private Color getColor(int i, int j) {
        return marchThroughImage(image, i, j);
    }

    public void getImg() {
        try {
            // get the BufferedImage, using the ImageIO class
            image = ImageIO.read(this.getClass().getResource("sms2.png"));
            System.out.println(" with" + image.getWidth());
            System.out.println(" height" + image.getHeight());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private Color marchThroughImage(BufferedImage image, int i, int j) {
        System.out.println("width, height: " + randomi + ", " + randomj);

        Color cor = new Color(image.getRGB(i, j));
        return cor;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        frame.add(new PixelCanvas());


        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Imagem usada:
[image: img]

Como ficou:
[image: imgalterada]

atenção: a imagem deve de ficar no mesmo local onde está o ficheiro .java caso nao queiras aí tens de alterar o caminho neste codigo:

```
 ImageIO.read(this.getClass().getResource("sms2.png"));
```

**EDIÇÃO DO CODIGO**

```
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import org.openide.util.Exceptions;

public class PixelCanvas extends Canvas {

    private static final int WIDTH = 100;
    private static final int HEIGHT = 100;
    private static BufferedImage image = null;
    private List<imgByPosicaoCor> listpixel = new ArrayList<>();

    public PixelCanvas() {
        getImg();
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);

        Collections.shuffle(listpixel);

        for (imgByPosicaoCor pixel : listpixel) {
            g.setColor(pixel.getCor());
            g.drawLine(pixel.getI(), pixel.getJ(), pixel.getI(), pixel.getJ());

            try {
                Thread.sleep(5);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Exceptions.printStackTrace(ex);
            }

        }

    }

    public void getImg() {
        try {
            // get the BufferedImage, using the ImageIO class
            image = ImageIO.read(this.getClass().getResource("sms2.png"));
            int whith = image.getWidth();
            int heigth = image.getHeight();

            System.out.println(" with" + image.getWidth());
            System.out.println(" height" + image.getHeight());

            for (int i = 0; i < whith; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < heigth; j++) {
                    imgByPosicaoCor pixel = new imgByPosicaoCor(i, j, new Color(image.getRGB(i, j)));
                    listpixel.add(pixel);
                }
            }
            System.out.println("TOTAL NA LISTA" + listpixel.size());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        frame.add(new PixelCanvas());
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

@Peter obrigado pela dica, agora o código está muito melhor (comparado com o primeiro).

Comment: Cara, show de bola. Vou tentar aplicar isto naquele fonte que encontrei, mais simples do que eu pensava. Com várias threads deve ficar super rápido, vou testar aí posto aqui novamente.

Comment: Tentei conforme você sugeriu, mas não obtive o mesmo efeito. Parece que ele é desenhado por retângulos. O que pode estar errado? Editei minha pergunta e adicionei o fonte. Obrigado.

Comment: aumento o tempo que ele adormece a desenhar cada ponto, aqui `Thread.sleep(100)` no meu pinta direito...

Comment: Editei o código, mas a logica continua a mesma, só apliquei a ajuda do peter.

Comment: Show Showww... Vou tentar aplicar no meu exemplo MultiThread esta solução.. Pra ver como fica.

Comment: Ficou bacana galera.. Valeu pela dica.. Agora tenho que fazer cada thread trabalhar com uma quantidade X de pixels.. Porque todas atualizam tudo.. Mas isto são outros 500. Obrigado.

Comment: sim penso que a logica agora não é muito difícil, so tens de dividir esse array em varios e mandas cada thread fazer um desses array

Comment: Sim sim, fiz um limitador pela quantidade de threads selecionadas, ficou show de boa. Valeu pela ajuda.

Answer (score 2):

Acho difícil tomar pixels aleatoriamente porque você forte chance de esquecer algumas.
Isto é o que acontece na solução dada pelo jsantos.

A solução é colocar todas as coordenadas de pixel (x, y) em uma tabela. Se a imagem é 60x60, assim você terá um array com 3600 entradas. Em seguida, você mistura o array. Depois, seria suficiente ler o array 'misturada' e cada vez, você vai ter a certeza de ter um novo pixel.
Para "misturar" um array em Java, você pode usar:

```
 Collections.shuffle(arrayList);
```